# Optimisation of a MSSQL Query - group by multiple columns

Tags: sql-server

Hey guys i could need some advice, i've the following 2 tables

Table **Model**:

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| DLTCountryCode |  SupplierID   | ModelNumber |    ModelDescription    |    Brand    | Fedas  | MeasurementUnit | MinModelNetPrice | MaxModelNetPrice | MinModelSuggestedRetailPrice | MaxModelSuggestedRetailPrice | MinModelInsteadPrice | MaxModelInsteadPrice | PictureAvailable |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| AT             | 9120048150008 |     2012266 | xxx                    | Brand       | 115946 | STK             |             6.05 |             6.05 |                        10.95 |                        10.95 |                    0 |                    0 |                1 |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+------------------------+-------------+--------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------------+
```

Table **ModelColorSizeInventory**:

```
+----------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------------------+
| DLTCountryCode |  SupplierID   | ModelNumber | ColorCode | Size |  ItemNumber   | Quantity |    InventoryDateTime    |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------------------+
| AT             | 9120048150008 |     2012266 |       801 | L    | 9008601584968 |        0 | 2017-09-29 11:16:02.347 |
| AT             | 9120048150008 |     2012266 |       801 | M    | 9008601584951 |        0 | 2017-09-29 11:16:02.347 |
| AT             | 9120048150008 |     2012266 |       801 | S    | 9008601584944 |        2 | 2017-09-29 11:16:02.347 |
| AT             | 9120048150008 |     2012266 |       801 | XL   | 9008601584975 |        4 | 2017-09-29 11:16:02.347 |
| AT             | 9120048150008 |     2012266 |       801 | XXL  | 9008601584982 |        6 | 2017-09-29 11:16:02.347 |
+----------------+---------------+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+----------+-------------------------+
```

And the following Query:

```
SELECT dccdm.*, SUM(dccdmcsi.[Quantity]) AS QuantityModel
FROM "Model" AS "dccdm"
LEFT JOIN ModelColorSizeInventory AS dccdmcsi ON dccdm.[ModelNumber] = dccdmcsi.[ModelNumber]
WHERE   (
    dccdm.ModelNumber IN('2012266')
)
AND dccdmcsi.[Quantity] >0
AND dccdm.[DLTCountryCode]='AT'
GROUP BY dccdm.[DLTCountryCode],dccdm.[SupplierID],dccdm.[ModelNumber],dccdm.[ModelDescription],dccdm.[Brand],dccdm.[Fedas],dccdm.[MeasurementUnit],dccdm.[MinModelNetPrice],dccdm.[MaxModelNetPrice],dccdm.[MinModelSuggestedRetailPrice],dccdm.[MaxModelSuggestedRetailPrice],dccdm.[MinModelInsteadPrice],dccdm.[MaxModelInsteadPrice],dccdm.[PictureAvailable]
```

This Query works as expected, i'm joining `ModelColorSizeInventory` to find out the sum of all variants with quantities

One thing that bothers me is the `group by` part, because if i skip the `group by` statement i'm getting the following error:

> Msg 8120, Column 'DLTCountryCode' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Since i'm not that familiar with MSSQL i ask the following question:

> How can i write down this query without using this complex GROUP BY clause

The reason behind this question is that writing down multiple columns in a group by statement feels wrong, in queries like these ... ;)

Comment: All columns that appear in the select that are not aggregated must appear in the group by clause, that's just how standard SQL works. If you don't need all columns in the result you could change the `select *` to `select <some specific columns>` and then you'd only have to group by them.

Comment: This is the SQL Standard behaviour (and it is now the default group by behavioir in mysql 5.7 onward) so better get used to it.  Suggest you never approach a group by query with `select *` as you need to specify the columnd for the group by anyway.

Comment: why would anyone downvote this question - @least provide an explanation ...

Answer (score 1):

You could use "subview" for grouped amounts, or simply use subquery in join, like:

```
Select dccdm.*, Isnull(dccdmcsi.SumQuantity,0)  
    FROM dbo.[Model]  dccdm LEFT JOIN 
    (Select ModelNumber, SUM([Quantity]) as SumQuantity from dbo.ModelColorSizeInventory GROUP BY ModelNumber) dccdmcsi  
    ON dccdm.ModelNumber=dccdmcsi.ModelNumber
```